# Delete a group of characters when backspace is pressed (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a textarea that contains new lines initialized by a number and a period:

```
<textarea autoFocus id="text-area"wrap="hard" 
  defaultValue ={this.state.textAreaVal} onKeyUp={this._editTextArea}/>
```

To illustrate this:

1. Line 1
2. Line 2
3. Line 3

I have a function that is called onKeyDown to check if the keycode is a backspace:

```
_editTextArea: function(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    if (key == 8) {
      //remove the whole line if the previous characters are a number followed by a period and then a space
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  },
```

My goal here is to delete the number and period with one backspace (how its done in microsoft word, imagine having an ordered list when you get to the bulletpoint or number or roman numeral and you press backspace, it not only deletes the whole list item but also it returns you to the previous list item's last char.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: By literally just doing what you said? Take the textarea's current text value, see if the text qualifies for your special treatment, if it does: split it on newlines, join up the slice of length "1 fewer than before" with newlines again, and set that as textAreaVal state value?

Comment: Why dont you just make this into a list item...

Comment: @YangLi you cannot put a list into a textarea

Comment: Do you need it to be in a textarea

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should give you enough to go on.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var str = "Hello world!  12.";

while (str.substring(str.length-1) == "." || isNumber(str.substring(str.length-1)))
{
str = str.substring(0,str.length-1)
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want but this maybe could help you:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
    lines.splice(this.value.substr(0, this.selectionStart).split("\n").length-1, 1);
    $('textarea').val(lines.join("\n"));
  }
})
```

You can try it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/swnhe2f0/1/

Comment: I am using reactJs, so I am trying to stay away from using jQuery. Could you explain this in JS?

Comment: `var lines = textarea.value.split('\n');
    lines.splice(this.value.substr(0, this.selectionStart).split("\n").length-1, 1);
    textarea.value = lines.join("\n");`

Comment: This is really simple, you read the textarea as an array by lines, after that I'm using splice() to remove current selected line and I use join () to join all the lines by lines